# Minimal graded free resolution of the ideal $I = (x^r, y^s) \subset k[x,y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

> What is the minimal free-graded resolution of the ideal $I = (x^r, y^s) \subset k[x,y]=R$ for $r,s \in \mathbb{N}$?

I tried reducing this down to $r = s = 1$ and I think it is $$0 \to R(-2) \to R(-1) \oplus R(-1) \to I \to 0.$$

I am guessing the if $r,s$ are just any natural numbers, I would get

$$0 \to R(-(s + r)) \to R(-s) \oplus R(-r) \to I \to 0$$

**Definition:** A graded resolution is *minimal* if $\phi_i(F_i) \subset mF_{i - 1}$ with $m = \left< x_1,\dots, x_n\right >$ whenever $F_i = Rg_1 \oplus \dots \oplus Rg_t$. The map $\phi( \sum_{i = 1}^{t} f_ig_i \to \sum_{i = 1}^{t} f_im_i ) = \sum_{i = 1}^{r} a_ie_i$. So $\phi_1(F_1) \subset mF_{i - 1}$ means every $a_i \in (x_1, \dots, x_n).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kernel of the map $\varphi:R^2\to I$ which sends $e_1=(1,0)$ to $X^r$ and $e_2=(0,1)$ to $Y^s$ is generated by $(Y^s,-X^r)$ (why?), and as you noticed it's isomorphic to $R$. Now the only thing which has do be done is to keep the track of gradings.

Thus we get $$0\to R(-(r+s))\stackrel{\psi}\to R(-r)\oplus R(-s)\stackrel{\varphi}\to I\to0,$$ where $\psi(f)=(Y^sf,-X^rf)$.

(Maybe it's useful to notice that $(R(-r)\oplus R(-s))_{r+s}$, the homogeneous component of degree $r+s$ of $R(-r)\oplus R(-s)$, equals $R_s\oplus R_r$.)

Comment: That is more or less my intuition. The whole "minimal" thing keeps throwing me off. Thank anyways.

Comment: @jacobsmith Are you trying to ask why is this resolution minimal?

Comment: I can't for some reason use "@" + username, but if you could elaborate on that, that would be helpful for me.

Comment: @jacobsmith The only thing to check is whether the image of $\psi$ is contained into $\mathfrak mR^2$, where $\mathfrak m=(X,Y)$. Or this is pretty clear: $\psi(1)=(Y^s,-X^r)=Y^s(1,0)-X^r(0,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

`Set S:=k[x,y]`
Yes, your guess is true.
 Since $x^r,y^s$ is a regular sequence, the Koszul complex, $K(x^r,y^s;S),$ provides a minimal graded free resolution of $S/I.$